# Deleting a button based on caption

Tags: excel, vba, button, shapes

Using Windows 10, Excel 2016. The code is in a module.

The code worked in 2015. Now it throws errors.

The code attempts to locate a button by its caption to delete it. There is only one button per worksheet.

```
DeleteShapesByCaption "Create a new Schedule of Values tab", wSht

Sub DeleteShapesByCaption( _
ByVal Caption As String, _
Optional ByVal WS As Worksheet = Nothing)

Dim Shp As Shape, i as long

If WS Is Nothing Then Set WS = ActiveSheet

WS.Unprotect Protect_Password
For i = WS.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set Shp = WS.Shapes(i)
    Select Case Shp.Type
    Case msoOLEControlObject
        If Shp.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Caption = Caption Then
            Shp.Delete  'This is where the error occurs
            Exit For
        End If
    Case msoFormControl
        'May be a button
        If Shp.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = Caption Then Shp.Delete
    End Select
Next i
WS.Protect Protect_Password
End Sub
```

The error occur at the first occurrence of `Shp.Delete`.

> RTE 404 Object Required

or

> RTE -2147024809 (80070057) The specified value is out of range

Context:

The workbook has a worksheet which is a template. Once the template is filled, it is copied for month 1. After the month 1 sheet is completed, the create_a_new_sheet_button is clicked to create a new sheet for month 2 and the create_a_new_sheet_button is supposed to be removed from the month 1 sheet. Each sheet only has one button.

I have used debug.print to confirm that the activesheet is the previous month's sheet.

I have modified cell formulae to reflect changes, but I don't think those changes are relevant to the errors because now the original 2015 workbook produces the errors.

The code executes as expected in creating the month 1 sheet. The only difference is that the create_a_new_sheet button is not deleted from the template page.

I can change the caption and disable the button as an error free work around, but it would be preferable to delete it.

Comment: Why not just delete all buttons on the active sheet, as to avoid any issues with shape#:   *Sheets(i).Buttons.Delete*

Comment: If you know the name of the command button, then use the command buttons name to delete it.`ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButtonName").Delete`

Comment: @Cyril  It is likely that as I add functionality, I will add additional buttons so I want code that is selective in what it deletes that I can continue to use.

Comment: @Davesexcel  I don't know the name of the command button. The captions will all be unique within the each sheet. The code does select the correct button. Selecting is not the problem, deleting is.

Comment: Is the button your code is failing to delete the same button that launched the process that attempts to delete itself? I've no idea if that's a problem but I can imagine it might cause an issue.

Comment: @CLR  Yes, it is attempting to delete the button that launched the process. It may be that Excel changed the way it handles that. I will try waiting an extra month before deleting the button to avoid this and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: A workaround might be to create a Sub that does the deleting but put it on an Application OnTime that occurs half a second after main sub is finished. Not ideal but might solve the problem.

Comment: Apparently code deleting a button that called the code is not a problem. The following code from another source executes without error.

Sub DeleteBtn()

    Dim btn As OLEObject, s As String

    s = "ButtonName"

    For Each btn In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects

        If TypeName(btn.Object) = "CommandButton" Then

            If btn.Object.Caption = s Then

                btn.Delete

            End If

        End If

    Next

End Sub

Comment: Apologies. It took me longer than allowed to try to get the code properly formatted.

Comment: Thia question has been answered, you need to check it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Delete button with specified caption. ActiveX control.

```
Sub DeleteBtn()
    Dim btn As OLEObject, s As String

    s = "ButtonName"
    For Each btn In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(btn.Object) = "CommandButton" Then
            If btn.Object.Caption = s Then
                btn.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```